# I can not find a suitable ARIMA, can anyone help me?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am doing a time series analysis but I can not find a suitable univariate Arima model for one particular series (it remains to show autocorrelation of the residuals or not all the parameters show significance).

I have tried to differentiate it in the order of 2 also.

I was wondering if anyone could help me?

Here is the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lHJx-sR32ZQW-3FVnu45jHiVtneSF44Y

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider using the `auto.arima` function from the "forecast" package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, I have already done that. Nevertheless, it suggests me an order 0,0,1 but when I review the residuals with the function checkresiduals the ljung-box tests shows residual autocorrelation.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Flick! I will

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MrFlick's comment, this seems more of a statistics question than about coding. That aside, here are some pointers that may help to get you started.

1. Let's take a look at the raw time series data.

   ```r
   library(forecast)
   autoplot(ts) + theme_minimal()
   ```

   [image]
2. Being aware of `forecast::auto.arima`s limitations in the presence of outliers, level shifts and other "abnormalities", `auto.arima` suggests a model of the form SARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0)<sub>12</sub>.

   **Note that this is different from an ARIMA(0,0,1) model that you mention in the comments!** We can see the difference, by writing down the equations for the SARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0)<sub>12</sub> model

   [image]

   and an ARIMA(0,0,1) model

   [image]

   The fit results are

   ```r
   fit <- auto.arima(ts)
   fit
   #Series: ts
   #ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0)[12] with non-zero mean
   #
   #Coefficients:
   #         ma1    sar1     mean
   #      0.3644  0.2302  15.8426
   #s.e.  0.1321  0.1298   0.4803
   #
   #sigma^2 estimated as 5.671:  log likelihood=-149.78
   #AIC=307.55   AICc=308.21   BIC=316.31
   ```
3. We take a look at the residuals along with their ACF and PACF

   ```r
   gg1 <- autoplot(fit$residuals) + theme_minimal()
   gg2 <- ggAcf(fit$residuals) + theme_minimal()
   gg3 <- ggPacf(fit$residuals) + theme_minimal()
   library(ggpubr)
   ggarrange(gg1, ggarrange(gg2, gg3, ncol = 2), nrow = 2)
   ```

[image]

### Conclusion

The distribution of the residuals look "ok": the residuals themselves look more-or-less stationary, and there is little (partial) auto-correlation at the first 9 lags. The spikes at lag 10 in the ACF and PACF may be indicative of other processes and would need further investigation.

Overall, an ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0)<sub>12</sub> model seems to give a decent fit to the data.

PS. Since you mention differencing in your main post: Be aware of the effects of (over)differencing.

---

### Sample data

```r
ts <- structure(c(15.6518870777097, 15.3322867608582, 17.6151603498542,
16.9445877027104, 14.7031828275352, 16.0412944212825, 16.861729056851,
13.452283131823, 13.2855709987104, 16.0124941065535, 16.5882352941176,
13.8099874808736, 16.9928053525937, 13.3337023302153, 15.4694135718804,
14.9111123979385, 16.1105207226355, 16.5585054080629, 13.5606661379857,
15.1856487275761, 20.4671985306778, 16.863711001642, 14.8349514563107,
16.0655394440664, 18.9172303262434, 18.9811320754717, 20.2998379254457,
15.8995316648271, 13.8971057363262, 18.3333810765132, 19.1311805257776,
16.7306443040217, 14.6418822305992, 20.1152852315643, 14.9894158704731,
13.5667766218388, 16.5179451090781, 12.3646258503401, 11.1907676167162,
16.7851016907621, 15.8961621664931, 18.853901818893, 18.216933524391,
16.4258603642395, 12.0362991336538, 14.6222482941739, 13.5002635740643,
11.3637532794897, 11.6990571483548, 17.3600605143722, 11.5196876016922,
17.7933147413488, 18.2443257676903, 16.983016983017, 22.6372784948589,
20.0215707422296, 12.2457223648902, 13.0610780897725, 13.7779017857143,
14.115336856392, 13.2063002533319, 15.7881424524484, 12.9566768310224,
16.7059081202431, 19.0690998564691, 18.4743742550656), .Dim = c(66L,
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "serie"), .Tsp = c(2013.5, 2018.91666666667,
12), class = "ts")
```